# Update JQUERY DATATABLE CELL In Database using Coldfusion and Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, coldfusion

I am trying to update my database table values from form docTableID into our database found in masterMaint.cfc. I seem to be stuck on the ajax post method where I want to POST the client side changes to the database when onUpdate is called.

```
masterMaint.cfc

<cfcomponent output="false">
    <cffunction name="updateDocuments" access="remote" output="false">
    
        <cfquery datasource="#mydatastore#" name="updateDocs">
            UPDATE MDL_MASTER_LIST set 
                site = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value='#FORM.docTable.site#'>,
                sections = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value='#FORM.docTable.sections#'>,
                tab = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value='#FORM.docTable.tab#'>,
                doc_number = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value='#FORM.docTable.doc_number#'>,
                description = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value='#FORM.docTable.description#'>,
                active = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value='#FORM.docTable.active#'>,
            WHERE doc_number = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value='#FORM.docTable.ARGUMENTS.original.doc_number#'>
        </cfquery>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Ajax: *This is where I am having issues with*

```
table.MakeCellsEditable({
    "onUpdate": updateDataBaseTable,
    "inputCss":'my-input-class',
    "columns": [0,1,2,3,9],
    "allowNulls": {
        "columns": [1],
        "errorClass": 'error'
    },


function updateDataBaseTable() {
    var updateDataBase = function(doc_number){

    $.ajax({
        post: "masterMaint.cfc",
        data:$('#docTableID').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {

            alert('OK');

        }
    });
};
```

Comment: This would have been a good start to a ColdFusion only question on updating data in a DB table. As soon as you add in datatables, it becomes a very complicated problem. I suggest dealing with one at a time.

Comment: And look up `<cfqueryparam>`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, James A Mohler. I'll look at those cf tags for query parameters.

Comment: As per @JamesAMohler's point. You are mishmashing client-side code and server-side code here, and are not being particularly clear as to which bit you need help with. Please revise to focus on the bit you need help with. The datatables code doesn't care about what the server-side code is; the server-side code doesn't know/care about the datatables code. What's the actual problem here? Pls revise the question.

Comment: Thanks @AdamCameron. I revised it to make it more clear. I am looking for the best way to reference the changes made in the datatable by the user and update he database table accordingly.

Comment: Right. It helps if you understand that the client doesn't know about CF, and CF doesn't know about the client. It sounds to me like you are getting a POST request from the client, and you don't know how to... do what... save the data to the DB? If so, forget about the HTML and the datatables side of things. They are irrelevant to your question. Your question is "I have this data coming in from a POST request and I need to save it into the DB". Show us an example of the data CF is receiving (using CODE, not a picture of it), and tell us which part of processing it you are struggling with.

Comment: Your code example should be a struct which demonstrates what you are receiving in the `form` scope, and whatever code you have to process it before trying to use in in an INSERT query (or UPDATE by the looks). You are still pretty much asking us to "fix my code", which is not what Stack Overflow is about. You say "I am still stuck". Stuck in _what way_?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction along with giving me a stack overflow lesson, for I am quite new to the platform and the programming world. @AdamCameron I have updated my question to reflect the area where I am stuck in. I seem to not be able to figure out how to make my post process update to the database going from client>server. I will look into using a struct to handle the object.

Comment: @Plumbboy77, your problem is still unclear... is there an error message on the client side or in on the server side that you can share? As Adam pointed out earlier, it would be better if you could replicate the structure of the data. One thing that stands out to me is that you are trying to reference a structure below the form scope (like #FORM.docTable.ARGUMENTS.original.doc_number#). I think that it is very unlikely that this is going to work unless there is some code we are not seeing that is deserializing the data (which I assume is in json) into a structure under the form scope.

Comment: another thing that stands out to me is that your client side code is not referencing the function/method name