# The cfgridupdate tag cannot find the grid named doclist

Tags: sql, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfgrid

I am following this guide on creating an editable cfgrid : [CFGRID GUIDE](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/requesting-and-presenting-information/building-dynamic-forms-with-cfform-tags/creating-data-grids-with-the-cfgrid-tag.html)

However, I am running into an error where it's saying cfgridupdate cannot find the gridname docgrid but I can't see where this could be caused. I have a page called handle_grid.cfm, which will run one of two queries to update data. Can someone spot what I might be missing here?

Master_Doc_Maint.cfm

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<!-- Importing jquery libraries -->
<title>Master List Maintenance</title>
<!--- Make sure the person running is an admin. --->
<cfif NOT listfindnocase(application.admins,application.wsl_cdsid)>
Sorry. You are not listed as an admin.
  <cfabort>
</cfif>


<!--- Get all the data from the database. --->
<cfquery datasource="mydatastore name="get_all_docs">
SELECT SITE,SECTIONS,TAB,DOC_NUMBER,DESCRIPTION,REV_LEVEL,REVISION_DATE,REVIEW_DATE,ADMIN,ACTIVE from MDL_MASTER_LIST 
   ORDER BY SITE,sections,TAB,DOC_NUMBER
</cfquery>

<cfform name="docgrid" action="handle_grid.cfm" > <!-- calls the handle program to process the changed data --> 

<cfgrid name="doclist" align="Top" autowidth="yes" bgcolor="FFF" colheaderbold="yes" selectmode="edit"
 format="html" griddataalign="left" gridlines="yes" query="get_all_docs" sort="yes" striperowcolor="FC6" striperows="yes"
 width=1650  insert="Yes" delete="yes">

<cfgridcolumn name="Site" width="100">
<cfgridcolumn name="Sections" width="100">
<cfgridcolumn name="Doc_Number" width="100" select="No">
<cfgridcolumn name="Description" width="300">
<cfgridcolumn name="Rev_Level" width="100">
<cfgridcolumn name="Revision_Date" width="100">
<cfgridcolumn name="Review_Date" width="100">
<cfgridcolumn name="Admin" width="100">
<cfgridcolumn name="Active" width="100">

</cfgrid>
<br>
<cfinput name="UpdateDocs" type="Submit" value="Update">

</cfform>

<cfgridupdate grid="doclist"
datasource="mydatastore"
tablename="MDL_MASTER_LIST">

Click <a href="Master_Doc_Maint.cfm">here</a> to display updated grid.

</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

handle_grid.cfm

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Master List Maintenance</title>
</head>
<!--- Make sure the person running is an admin. --->
<cfif NOT listfindnocase(application.admins,application.wsl_cdsid)>
Sorry. You are not listed as an admin.
  <cfabort>
</cfif>
<body>

<h3>Grid values for Form.firstgrid row updates</h3>

<cfif isdefined("Form.docgrid.rowstatus.action") is True>

<cfloop index = "counter" from = "1" to =
#arraylen(Form.docgrid.rowstatus.action)#>

<cfoutput>
The row action for #counter# is:
#Form.docgrid.rowstatus.action[counter]#
<br>
</cfoutput>

<cfswitch expression="#Form.docgrid.rowstatus.action[counter]#">
<cfcase value = "U">
<cfquery name="query_insert" datasource="mydatastore">
UPDATE MDL_MASTER_LIST
SET
    active = <cfqueryparam value = '#form.docgrid.active[counter]#' CFSQLType="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">,
    admin = <cfqueryparam value = '#form.docgrid.admin[counter]#' CFSQLType="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">,
    description = <cfqueryparam value = '#form.docgrid.description[counter]#' CFSQLType="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">,
    doc_number = <cfqueryparam value = '#form.docgrid.doc_number[counter]#' CFSQLType="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">,
    is_contact = <cfqueryparam value = #form.docgrid.is_contact[counter]# CFSQLType="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">,
    is_file = <cfqueryparam value = #form.docgrid.is_file[counter]# CFSQLType="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">,
    review_date = <cfqueryparam value = #createodbcdate(form.docgrid.review_date[counter])# CFSQLType="CF_SQL_DATE">,
    revision_date = <cfqueryparam value = #createodbcdate(form.docgrid.revision_date[counter])# CFSQLType="CF_SQL_DATE">,
    rev_level = <cfqueryparam value = '#form.docgrid.rev_level[counter]#' CFSQLType="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">,
    sections = <cfqueryparam value = '#form.docgrid.sections[counter]#' CFSQLType="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">,
    site = <cfqueryparam value = '#form.docgrid.site[counter]#' CFSQLType="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">,
    tab = <cfqueryparam value = '#form.docgrid.tab[counter]#' CFSQLType="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">
WHERE doc_number = <cfqueryparam value = '#form.docgrid.original.doc_number[counter]#' CFSQLType="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">
</cfquery>
</cfcase>
<cfcase value ="D">
         <cfquery name="query_delete" datasource="mydatastore">
            DELETE FROM MDL_MASTER_LIST WHERE doc_number = <cfqueryparam value = '#form.docgrid.original.doc_number[counter]#' CFSQLType="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">
         </cfquery>
      </cfcase>'
      </cfswitch>
</cfloop>
</cfif>

Click <a href="Master_Doc_Maint.cfm">here</a> to display updated grid.

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possibly not that helpful, but if this is new code: *don't use the UI tags in CFML*. Use a proper JS client side library to render your grid, and then send the stuff back to the CF server to process. The CF stuff hasn't really been "the way to do things" for over a decade, are poorly maintained, and you'll struggle to get help with them.

Answer (score 1):

In your link to the [CFGRID docs](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/requesting-and-presenting-information/building-dynamic-forms-with-cfform-tags/creating-data-grids-with-the-cfgrid-tag.html):

Under "Creating an editable grid":

> Pass grid edits to a page that includes the `cfgridupdate` tag, which automatically extracts the form variable values and passes that data directly to the data source. Using the `cfquery` tag gives you complete control over interactions with your data source. The `cfgridupdate` tag provides a much simpler interface for operations that do not require the same level of control.

This seems that the `cfgridupdate` statement should be on a separate page from the `cfgrid`. You should have the page with the grid, edits would post to the page with `cfgridupdate`. You have them both on the same page.

To reiterate Adam's comment, `CFGRID` and the other CF UI controls are straight trash compared to modern UI libraries. If this is new code, I would recommend replacing this grid with one of these:

- https://datatables.net/
- https://www.ag-grid.com/

**Update:**

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-g-h/cfgridupdate.html

There's an example here that shows a condition check before using `cfgridupdate`.

```
<!--- If the gridEntered form field exists, the form was submitted. Perform gridupdate. ---> 
<cfif IsDefined("form.gridEntered") is True> 
    <cfgridupdate grid = "FirstGrid" 
        dataSource = "cfdocexamples" Keyonly="true" 
        tableName = "CourseList"> 
</cfif>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips @Adrian J. Moreno. Yes, cfgridupdate call is on another cfm page, which when I try gives me the same error. This is in-face new code. 

Also, to answer yours and Adam's comment on replacing the grid with a more modern grid:
I have an open question for this actually found here, where I am having problems with POSTING to the server side and getting an updated grid to the client; which is where I am currently stuck on this problem. 
[Here is the link if interested](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73775443/19888734)